# Websphere 8.5 - java.net.UnknownHostException

Tags: exception, websphere

I'd tried to start websphere 8.5 and get UnknownHostException,
and I saw this:http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21501971

I did set the hostname and reboot, but still get this exception, what else have to do?

Comment: Attach stack trace with error and info what is your hostname.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UnknownHostException** certainly refers to a name resolution issue.

Since this happens during the Websphere startup I guess this is a profile relocation, i.e. either you have changed the machine hostname or you moved the websphere profile to another machine.

If this is the case follow the guidelines mentioned [here](http://java.boot.by/ibm-317/apas02.html).

Otherwise add the machine hostname you are trying to call(i.e. through EJB(?)) in your /etc/hosts file.